How to position fabric js Image and its clipPath after they are inserted into a group?
I'm using Fabric.js (version 5.3.0) In my app I need to implement the Crop functionality where user should be able to crop any image. The user should also be able to restart the crop without needing to upload an image again (this part is not included in the fiddle).
The approach I use is to create a transparent fabric.Rect and use it as the cropArea, this rect becomes the clipPath of the image to be cropped so the user can select the desired portion of the image. When user clicks "crop done", I create a fabric.Group with the original Image and its cropArea so the user can manipulate(scale, rotate, move) the resulting image.
The problem I'm facing is that when both the image and its cropArea get added to the Group, there is a little "offset" on their position. The image sort of "jumps" to the side and the boundaries of the group don't match the resulting image.
Here is a fiddle to ilustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/marcolina850/eqkfo5pv/171/
Html:
   <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="440"></canvas>

      <button id="startCrop">
         start cropping
      </button>
      <button id="cropDone">
         crop done
      </button>
    


JS:
var canvas

function init() {
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    preserveObjectStacking: true,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  });

  const workArea = new fabric.Rect({
    id: 'workArea',
    width: 540,
    height: 340,
    absolutePositioned: true,
    fill: '#ffffff',
    selectable: false,
    hoverCursor: 'default'
  });
  canvas.add(workArea);
  workArea.center();
  canvas.renderAll();

  fabric.Image.fromURL('https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg', (img) => {
    img.set({
      scaleX: 0.5,
      scaleY: 0.5,
      id: 'croppingObject',
      clipPath: workArea
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    img.center()

    canvas.requestRenderAll()
    croppingObject = img
  })
}


$("#cropDone").on("click", function() {
  const cropArea = getObjectById('cropArea')
  const croppingObject = getObjectById('croppingObject')
  const {
    aCoords: croppingCoordinates
  } = cropArea;
  const workarea = canvas.getObjects().find(obj => obj.id === 'workarea');
  canvas.discardActiveObject();
  cropArea.set('stroke', 'none');
  cropArea.set('strokeDashArray', null);
  cropArea.set('selectable', false);
  croppingObject.set('selectable', false);

  const group = new fabric.Group([cropArea, croppingObject], {
    clipPath: workarea,
    left: cropArea.left,
    top: cropArea.top,
    width: cropArea.aCoords.tr.x - cropArea.aCoords.tl.x,
    height: cropArea.aCoords.br.y - cropArea.aCoords.tr.y,
    originX: cropArea.originX,
    originY: cropArea.originY
  });

  group.setCoords();
  canvas.add(group);
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$("#startCrop").on("click", function() {
  const croppingObject = getObjectById('croppingObject')
  const workArea = getObjectById('workArea')

  const {
    top,
    left,
    height,
    width,
    scaleX,
    scaleY
  } = croppingObject;

  var cropArea = new fabric.Rect({
    top,
    left,
    height,
    width,
    scaleX,
    scaleY,
    fill: 'transparent',
    stroke: '#ccc',
    strokeDashArray: [4],
    id: 'cropArea',
    clipPath: workArea,
    absolutePositioned: true
  });
  croppingObject.set('clipPath', cropArea)
  croppingObject.setCoords()
  canvas.add(cropArea);
  canvas.setActiveObject(cropArea);
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function getObjectById(id) {
  return canvas.getObjects().find(o => o.id === id)
}

init()

I tried different options to position the Group but in the end nothing worked. The Fabric.js docs do mention that objects in group are all positioned relative to the center of the group, so I guess that's what is causing this offset, but I'm still not able to figure out how to position them properly.
Thanks in advance!

I belive that the issue you're facing with the offset when adding both the image and its crop area to the group arises from the fact that the positions of these objects are not being handled correctly when added to the group. To fix this, you need to adjust the positions of the objects relative to the group's origin.
